# Delphi ReportBuilder how to liberate a file from TppTextPipeline

Tags: delphi, reportbuilder, tstringlist

I need to find a way to free up the file used by my TppTextPipeline. After I print the report once I cannot reprint it because I get a: error file already in use.
I guess its because I am trying to rewrite to the file before reprinting. How would I tell a TppTextPipeline object to "free" its file?

Basically I have something like:

```
buffer.SaveToFile('test.txt');

ppTextPipeline1.FileName :=   'test.txt';

pprReport1.Print;
```

And would need to be able to call this twice so somehow "freeing" text.txt in between calls.

Answer (score 1):

Well I found that I can call:

```
pprTicketsSold.CloseDataPipelines;
```

After printing and it seems to do what I want. I'll leave the question open in case I am dead wrong or some better solution exists.